# JobScheduler Idle and periodic behaviour

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

If We schedule a periodic job for every X hours using job scheduler and set job to run when device is idle. What will happen if the device is not idle for X hours?

Will the job run every X hours irrespective of device idle status or Job will run only when device comes into idle state.

Answer (score 0):

For android version <= 6.0 . job is executed even if the idle constraints are not satisfied - http://androidxref.com/6.0.1_r10/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#209

For android version >=7 job will be executed only when the constraints are satisfied - http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-10.0.0_r36/xref/frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/job/controllers/JobStatus.java#1119